# How to get larger jumplist in Start Menu for long filenames

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-7-x64, startmenu, jump-list

I'm using Windows 7 Professional x64 and I have been trying to increase the width of the Start Menu for the jumplist without any success.

The problem is, I work with several files that have similar names, then when I pin these files to the jumplist on Start Menu (I'm not talking about jumplist on Taksbar), the names show truncated since the jumplist is not wide enough to accommodate the full filename, then all files appear to have same name. It is a pain because I have to hover mouse over the filename and wait to have the full filename shown, if it is not the file that I want, then I have to do same for next file until I find the correct one that I want to open. It slows things down. :(

I'm wondering if it is even possible to make jumplist larger to accommodate the full filename and how to do this. Any help much appreciate.

I think image makes clearer what I said above:

[image]

Thank you!